# Which page of UICollectionView is visible?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Right now I have a UICollectionView set up with horizontal paging. I have sized my cells to fit the screen so that there is only ever one visible(unless you are scrolling).

What I wish to do is get the index path of the cell that is in view once you have stopped scrolling. This is because other parts of the view are dependent on the information that is currently visible.

I have set up a function in the scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating function and I am close but I still don't seem to understand how it is grabbing the cells.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if( lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x && lastPointVisited > 0)
    {
        lastPointVisited -= 1

        print("Scrolling Right")
    }
    else if(lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x && lastPointVisited < myPoints.count - 1)
    {
        lastPointVisited += 1

        print("Scrolling Left")
    }

    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
}
```

This gets me accurate results if I am very careful about scrolling. Going fast or only half scrolling a page so that it snaps back seems to throw everything off.

Comment: Why are you using `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` instead of say `scrollViewDidScroll` or `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation`.  It's not clear from your question what you're actually observing that is not what you expect to observe.  What is the actual problem?  What is "thrown off"?

Comment: Why not use a `UIPageViewController` instead?

Comment: I was using `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` because I wanted to begin moving a map based on what was coming next in the collection view. Although after following @RajatJangra advice from the answer below I see that it makes no difference in the timing and waiting until the scrolling was complete solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me If I put the same code in these two delegates at same time

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //code here
}
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    //code here
}
```

instead of writing it in

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

It gives me the exact value of index whether it is scrolling fast or half scrolled.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah. Just changing from scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating to scrollViewDidEndDecelerating solved my issue. It was the partial scrolling in between moving from one page to another that was throwing off my function. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to get page number

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
        let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)
        print("Page Number : \(page)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let cellObj = collectionViewDemo.visibleCells[0]
        print(collectionViewDemo.indexPath(for: cellObj))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code it will be always effective to find the visible collectionView page

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageWidth = scrollview.frame.width
    let pageIndex = scrollview.frame.width
                let indexTemp = Int((scrollview.contentOffset.x + 
     pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)

       print(pageIndex)

}
```